# C# I`m trying to search for a name in a sqlite table

Tags: c#, sqlite, system.data.sqlite

I`m using this code to search for a number in a sqlite Table

```
String insSQL2 = "select * from Produtos where nome =" + txtBuscaNome.Text;
```

but when I try to use it to search for a name I get an error. Why?

The error I get is

System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteException was unhandled

SQL logic error or missing database

no such column: "the text I typed"

Comment: Don't you think that telling us what the error was would help us diagnose your problem?

Comment: I would heed Simon's advice below, and research parameterized queries to protect your code from SQL injection attacks.

Comment: Probably I will try it in the future but now I`m learning the very basics of C# and sqlite and this is just a small program to keep control of my coins... Also if you have a good basic example of a more secure way to use sqlite in C# I would apreciate.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ignoring the fact that your code is completely open to [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection), you need to enclose strings in single quotes in SQL.

So your code should be this:

```
String insSQL2 = 
    "select * from Produtos where nome = '" + txtBuscaNome.Text + "'";
//                                       ^^ here                   ^^ here
```

Comment: Thanks A Lot! I`m going to be the only one using this so security is not a concern, but it is always good to learn somenthing new.